# How to access parent class params literals?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Using Scala 2.x macros, how to access literals passed to parent classes when defining subclasses, typically with ADTs such as the following:

```scala
sealed abstract class Base(val s: String, val i: Int)
object Base {
  case object A extends Base("a", 1)
  case object B extends Base("b", 2)
  case class C(override val s: String) extends Base(s, 3)
}
```

For object A, I would like to know parameter values are literals `"a"` and `1`.
For object B, I would like to know parameter values are literals `"b"` and `2`.
For case class C, I would like to know the second parameter is literal `3`.

How can I accomplish this with Scala 2.x macros?

Comment: This appears to be an X:Y question?

Comment: OK. I removed the last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation and getting inspiration from  [bwmcadams /
supreme-macro-adventure](https://github.com/bwmcadams/supreme-macro-adventure/blob/master/deck/scala-macros_static.md), it looks like one solution is based on the combination of [*Macro Paradise*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) and the creation of an `@ADT` annotation.

*Macro paradise* provides a mechanism to expand annotations on ADTs to rewrite them, thanks to the `macroTransform` function.

```scala
import scala.annotation.{compileTimeOnly, StaticAnnotation}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class ADT extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ADT.impl
}

object ADT {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    val trees = annottees.map(_.tree)
    val rewritten = trees match {
      case (cd: ClassDef) :: q"object $name { ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        $body match {
          case q"case object $name extends $_($literal, $_)" :: tail =>
            [...]
        }
      case _ =>
        trees
    }

    c.Expr[Any](q"{..$rewritten}")
  }
}
```

With the help of quasiquotes, one can navigate `$body` and pattern match the different cases to access the arguments passed to the parent class (here `$literal`). Finally, one returns the rewritten ADT.